# How to run Windows Containers on Local Kubernetes?

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, containers, kubectl

I'm having a .Net Framework and .NetCore Containers and I would like to run them in Kubernetes. I have Docker Desktop for Windows installed and Kubernetes with it. How can I run these Windows Containers in Kubernetes?
[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/windows/user-guide-windows-nodes/) Documentation specifies how to create a Windows Node on Kubernetes, but it is very confusing. As I am on windows machine and I see linux based commands in there (And no mention of what OS you need to run all those). I am on Windows 10 Pro Machine. Is there a way to run these containers on Kubernetes?

When I try to create a Pod with Windows Containers, it fails with the following error message "Failed to pull image 'imagename'; rpc error: code = Unknown desc = image operating system 'windows' cannot be used on this platform"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on StackOverflow Srinath

To my knowledge you can't run Windows Containers on local version of Kubernetes at this moment. When you enable Kubernetes option in your Docker Desktop for Windows installation, the Kubernetes cluster is simply run inside Linux VM (with its own Docker Runtime for Linux containers only) on Hyper-V hypervisor.

The other solution for you is to use for instance a managed version of Kubernetes with Windows nodes from any of popular cloud providers. I think relatively easy to start is Azure (if you don't have an Azure subscription, create a [free](https://azure.microsoft.com/free/?WT.mc_id=A261C142F) trial account, valid for 12 months).

I would suggest you to use an old way to run Kubernetes on Azure, a service called Azure Container Service aka ACS, for one reason, it has been verified by me to be working well with Windows Containers, especially for testing purposes (I could not achieve the same with its successor, called [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough)):

Run following commands in Azure Cloud Shell, and your cluster will be ready to use in few minutes.

```
az group create --name azEvalRG --location eastus
az acs create -g azEvalRG -n k8s-based-win -d k8s-based-win --windows --agent-count 1 -u azureuser --admin-password 'YourSecretPwd1234$' -t kubernetes --location eastus
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think using ACS/AKS would work to run windows containers. However I want to run my Windows containers on kubernetes on local pc as this is kind of a requirement to run WIndows Containers in K8s on Windows 10 machine. Check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/)

Comment: As per your article: 'Windows Server 2019 is the only Windows operating system supported, enabling Kubernetes Node on Windows'. No chance that your Windows 10 Pro OS can serve as worker for your local Kubernetes cluster.
Without support you can use: Windows Server, version 1709 or later, but still Windows 10 is not on the list. As a kind of remedy you can still build and run Windows Containers on your Windows 10 machine, here is the container version compatibility list:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility